# What does "流れるように" mean?

Tags: translation

When someone says "流れるように", does it automatically mean "流れるように動く"?

Cause I found the hashtag "流れるように" on twitter and I was wondering if this is the case.

https://twitter.com/hashtag/%E6%B5%81%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB?src=hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal meaning of 流れるように is just "as if flowing" or "like a flow". The corresponding verb depends on the context, as shown below, but it's usually *not* 動く.

This hashtag is far from popular (less than 100 tweets in the last 5 years), and apparently it is used in **many** different ways. You have to determine the meaning of 流れるように on a case-by-case basis, and to do so, you have to be fairly good at Japanese net slang.

- "(physically) smooth", "like a streamline"
- "like a chain reaction", "like an avalanche"

  > - ジャニーズもSMAPの一件から流れるように様々な動きがありますね
- "without resisting", "without causing trouble"

  > - 自然に生きればいいんだよ #自然 #ありのまま #流れるように #宇宙
- "as always", "smoothly", "without pause/break"

  > - #帰宅して #流れるように #PCへ
  > - 5話からメドレーそして5話  #流れるように
- (joke) "as if it were natural", "boldly without hesitation", "daringly"

  > - どぎゃーーーーーん柏戦日曜やないかやすむ　#流れるように
  > - お見舞いありがとうございます。わーやさしいなーろくさんは。なにかください。#流れるように
- (joke) "Here I said something surprising knowing no one would care now", "I said it nonchalantly as if it were nothing, but I'm just kidding", "Everyone is saying something unusual, so I'm saying this too"

  > - 最近毎日ウィンナー食べてるけど別に私ホモだからね　#流れるように
  > - ちょっと人妻と絡んできます #流れるように

The last one is very tricky, but it's in the same vein as [この流れなら言える](https://sabanavi.com/net/kononagarenaraieru/), which is a recurring joke added before someone says something vulgar/strange in the middle of an exchange.